# How to asynchronusly read JSON and use its data in android?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am trying to download code from a link as JSON(JSON Link: https://api.myjson.com/bins/ehzqu) and render it. Here is the code:

```
public class FetchJSON extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
    String data = "";
    String id, name, address, lat, lng, type = "";

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        Log.i("", "TEST");
        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://api.myjson.com/bins/ehzqu");
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line = "";
            while(line!=null){
                line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                data = data + line;
            }
            Log.i("", "TEST2");
            JSONArray JA = new JSONArray(data);
            for( int i = 0 ; i < JA.length();i++)
            {
                JSONObject JO = (JSONObject) JA.get(i);
                //Log.i("", JO.toString());

                id = (String) JO.get("id");
                name = (String) JO.get("name");
                address = (String) JO.get("address");

                lat = JO.get("lat").toString();
                lng = JO.get("lng").toString();
                Log.i("JSON Values", lat + " " + lng);  //////////////////////////
                type = (String) JO.get("type");
            }
            Log.i("", "TEST3");

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {

        TrackDifferentLocation.data.setText(this.data);


        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    }

    public void printLat()
    {
        Log.i("", lat);
    }

    public String getLat (){
        return lat;
    }
    public String getLng (){
        return lng;
    }
    public String getName (){
        return name;
    }
    public String getAddress (){
        return address;
    }
    public String getID (){
        return id;
    }
    public String getType (){
        return type;
    }
}
```

In another class, I then have the following;

```
public class TrackDifferentLocation extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    String json_string;
    public static TextView data;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Tracking location...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_track_different_location);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        Log.i("", "onMapReady()");
        FetchJSON f = new FetchJSON();

        // f.execute();
        // f.printLat();
        //Log.i("", f.getLat());
        //Log.i("", f.getLng());

        double latitude = Double.valueOf(f.getLat());
        double longitude = Double.valueOf(f.getLng());
        LatLng latlng = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
        //Log.d("Marker: ", m.getTitle());
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlng));
    }

    //Part of menu see following
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == android.R.id.home){
            //ends the activity
            this.finish();
        }
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.mapTypeNone:
                mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);
                break;
            case R.id.mapTypeNormal:
                mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                break;
            case R.id.mapTypeTerrain:
                mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
                break;
            case R.id.mapTypeSatellite:
                mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
                break;
            case R.id.mapTypeHybrid:
                mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

But upon running this code, the application on android, crashes.

If I hard-code the latitude and longitude as set figures in the getLat/getLng functions, the code works perfectly. Please note, I have removed the import and package names for this question.

EDIT:

```js
public class TrackDifferentLocation extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    LatLng mLatlng;
    String json_string;
    public static TextView data;
    LatLng latLng = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Tracking location...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_track_different_location);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        //new FetchJSON.execute(); //Not valid syntax
        FetchJSON f = new FetchJSON();
    }

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    Log.i("", "onMapReady()");
    displayMarkers();
}
    private void displayMarkers(){
        if(mMap == null) return;
        if(mLatlng == null) return;

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(mLatlng));
    }

    //Part of menu see following
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == android.R.id.home){
            //ends the activity
            this.finish();
        }
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.mapTypeNone:
                mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);
                break;
            case R.id.mapTypeNormal:
                mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                break;
            case R.id.mapTypeTerrain:
                mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
                break;
            case R.id.mapTypeSatellite:
                mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
                break;
            case R.id.mapTypeHybrid:
                mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    class FetchJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, LatLng> {
        String JSONStr = "";
        String name, address, type = "";
        String lat = "";
        String lng = "";
        String id = "";
        //double lat, lng;
        int idInt;
        double latDouble = -1;
        double lngDouble = -1;

        protected LatLng doInBackground(String... args) {
            //LatLng latLng = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL("https://api.myjson.com/bins/ehzqu");
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String line = "";
                while (line != null) {
                    line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                    JSONStr = JSONStr + line;
                }
                Log.i("", "TEST2");

                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(JSONStr);
                JSONArray array = obj.getJSONArray("server response");
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject o = array.getJSONObject(i);
                    id = o.optString("id");
                    name = o.optString("name");
                    address = o.optString("address");
                    lat = o.optString(lat);
                    lng = o.optString("lng");
                    latDouble = Double.parseDouble(lat);
                    lngDouble = Double.parseDouble(lng);

                    latLng = new LatLng(latDouble, lngDouble);

                    Log.i("JSON Values", lat + " " + lng);
                    type = o.optString("type");
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.e(TAG, "FetchJSON --- " + ex.getMessage());
            }
            return latLng;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(LatLng latLng) {
            if (latLng != null) {
                mLatlng = latLng;
                displayMarkers();
            }
        }
        private void displayMarkers(){
            if(mMap == null) return;
            if(mLatlng == null) return;

            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(mLatlng));
        }
}
}
```

Comment: Please provide stack trace

Comment: FetchJSON is an asynchronous task, so when you try to access f.getLat(), it has no value yet because the task has not completed, you need to wait for the FetchJSON object to complete before trying to access the getLat() getter.

Comment: I'm pretty certain this is java, not javascript.

Comment: Please could you provide an answer with a fix so I can mark it fixed

Comment: Sorry, I don't know java.

Comment: @JackGiffin correct, autocorrect changed it for me when I posted

Comment: Are you certain that `FetchJSON` is not throwing a `JSONException` error??

Comment: My logcat is not actually working right now - Im not sure why - but nothing is showing up in it which is making like much more difficult to solve this.

Comment: It should be `new FetchJSON().execute();` I forgot the `()` after `FetchJSON`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data you showed in your link is not an `JSONArray`.

> {"server
>   response":[{"id":"991","name":"GPSname","address":"GPSaddress","lat":"52.948616","lng":"-1.169131","type":"GPStype"}]}

It is a `JSONObject` with a `JSONArray` child.

.

**EDIT**

Create a class variable for the `Latlng` values.

`Latlng mLatlng;`

Now in your `onCreate()` method add: 
`loadLocation();`

Here is the new code:

```
 @Override
 public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
     mMap = googleMap;

     displayMarker();
 }


 private void loadLocation() {
     new FetchJSON().execute();
 }


 class FetchJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, LatLng> {

     @Override
     protected LatLng doInBackground(String... params) {
         LatLng latLng = null;
         try {
             URL url = new URL("https://api.myjson.com/bins/ehzqu");
             HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
             InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
             BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

             StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
             String line = "";
             while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                 stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
             }
             bufferedReader.close();

             String json = stringBuilder.toString();

             Log.e(TAG, "Return = " + json);
             String lat= "";
             String lng= "";
             JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);
             JSONArray array = obj.getJSONArray("server response");
             for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
                 JSONObject o = array.getJSONObject(i);

                 lat = o.optString("lat");
                 lng = o.optString("lng");
             }

             Log.e(TAG, "Lat = " + lat);
             Log.e(TAG, "lng = " + lng);

             double latDouble = Double.parseDouble(lat);
             double lngDouble = Double.parseDouble(lng);

             latLng = new LatLng(latDouble, lngDouble);
         }
         catch (Exception ex) {
             Log.e(TAG, "doInBackground --- " + ex.getMessage());
         }
         return latLng;
     }


     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(LatLng latLng) {
         try{
             if(latLng != null){
                 mLatLng = latLng;
                 displayMarker();
             }

         }
         catch(Exception ex){
             Log.e(TAG, "onPostExecute" + ex.getMessage());
         }
     }

 }

 private void displayMarker(){
     if(mMap == null) return;
     if(mLatLng == null) return;

     MarkerOptions markerOption = new MarkerOptions();
     markerOption.position(mLatLng);
     mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mLatLng, zoomFactor));
     mMap.addMarker(markerOption);
 }
```

The result on my device:

[image]

When your GoogleMap is ready it will call `displayMarkers()`. If the "mLatLng" is `null` because the `FetchJSON` is not finished it nothing happens.

You could call `FetchJSON` from the `onMapReady()` method as suggested, but why not download the data in a background thread while you system is getting the GoogleMap ready?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response - I have updated my code to yours, but when running (emulator, nexus 6) the map loads, but its at location -1,0, -1,0. I hard coded a latDouble = -5 into the "do inbackground" - and it still shows -1.0,-1.0 - so I dont think its running?

Comment: Its not unfortunately, which is really frustrating!

Comment: I think my issue is my debugger. A minute ago everything worked as it should, logcat and all. also, I my data string is receiving the JSON via the httpconnection - the JSON array printed to the logcat. Now, nothing is ocurring in my logcat, or happening when I rub my debugger. Its struggling to "attach to application".

Comment: Looking at the code now - the line .execute() doesnt appear to be a valid one?
Also, the DisplayMarkers() method - have you put that in the DetchJSON activity/class or the TrackDifferentLocation activity/class? but it makes sense what youre doing

Comment: Also, what have you returned as the result? Result alone doesnt appear to be a valid variable! For the .execute issue, I initiated with " FetchJSON f = new FetchJSON(); "

Comment: @JamesDoh96 :: Opps "result" should be "latLng".  `FetchJSON` is subclassed in the `TrackDifferentLocation` Activity. `displayMarkers()` is also a class method in the `TrackDifferentLocation` Activity.

Comment: I suspected the result.  However I meant the .execute is not valid syntax for android studio. I have placed the code as per my edit in the original question - but upon running, no marker at all appears now, suggesting its not gettingto the display markers function

Comment: @JamesDoh96 :: I wrote the code in a standard text editor--so I didn't have the advantage of auto code completion. `new FetchJSON().execute(); ` is the correct syntax--I forgot the `()` after `FetchJSON`! In any case, you must call `.execute()` for the `AsyncTask` to run. If you prefer to write out `FetchJSON f = new FetchJSON();` then you must also call `f.execute();`

Comment: You are correct, that is the syntax. I should have noticed that, apologies! Running the full code doesn't produce any marker now however

Comment: I managed to get my temperamental debugger working... kind of. The JSONStr populates with the JSON as expected. I think the issue might be somewhere around the while loop? The variables in the for loop below the while loop are never populated.

Comment: @JamesDoh96 :: I got mine to work! I forgot to add the part we we need to move the camera! Take a look at the `displayMarkers()` method again.. I have added `mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mLatLng, 17.3f));`. let me know what happens.

Comment: Hi Barns, Okay so I have no explanation for this. I put a Log.d("",latlng) before it was returned and run the debugger. latlng and all variables from JSON string were empty. I then went through each line putting a break point and running one line at a time. By the time I run it through to get to the end, everything worked, and the original Log.d("",latlng) then returned the expected value. So basically it works! Thank you so much! However, I cant exaplin why the debugger suddenly made it work??

Comment: @JamesDoh96 :: Take a look at the newly edited code! I got mine to work! I have added a screen shot from my device to show how it looks for me.

Comment: I have mine working too now! I created a new myjson with more random coordinates and it updated to them correctly too. The last thing is to ensure that the map auto-moves to the marker every 5 seconds. Ideas?

Comment: I've marked your answer as the correct solution thing too!

Comment: @JamesDoh96 :: I have an idea about the animation. Please post an new question on SO and I will take a look at it!  .......Sorry about the lapses in my code--I was doing everything in a standard text editor and not in my IDE so I didn`t have the auto code completion.

Comment: I have posted up a new question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50438095/how-to-correctly-animate-a-map-created-in-android-studio-to-follow-the-marker

Answer (score 3):

FetchJSON is an asynchronous task, so when you try to access `f.getLat()`, it has no value yet because the task has not completed, you need to wait for the FetchJSON object to complete before trying to access the `getLat()` getter.

**I reckon you can probably do something along these lines**:

pass the map to the FetchJSON object:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    Log.i("", "onMapReady()");
    FetchJSON f = new FetchJSON(mMap);
}
```

and set the marker in your FetchJSON when the latitude and longitude are known:

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    ....
    lat = JO.get("lat").toString();
    lng = JO.get("lng").toString();
    type = (String) JO.get("type");

    // Set the marker here:
    double latitude = Double.valueOf(f.getLat());
    double longitude = Double.valueOf(f.getLng());
    LatLng latlng = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlng));
    ....
}
```

**Or better practice** is probably to do it in the `onPostExecute` method, which is called after the `doInBackground` method ([See API here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute(Result))):

```
LatLng latlng = null;

@Override
protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
    ...
    double latitude = Double.valueOf(f.getLat());
    double longitude = Double.valueOf(f.getLng());
    latlng = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
    ....
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
    if(latlng != null)
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlng));
}
```

**Also, you are not reading the JSON correctly**, you are expecting a JSONArray when it is actually a JSONObject, with a JSONArray inside. This example works for the JSON you get at your link:

```
String data = "{\"server response\":[{\"id\":\"991\",\"name\":\"GPSname\",\"address\":\"GPSaddress\",\"lat\":\"52.948616\",\"lng\":\"-1.169131\",\"type\":\"GPStype\"}]}";
Log.i("TAG", data);

String id, name, address, lat, lng, type;
try {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(data);
    JSONArray serverResponse = json.getJSONArray("server response");

    for (int i = 0; i < serverResponse.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject JO = (JSONObject) serverResponse.get(i);
        id = (String) JO.get("id");
        name = (String) JO.get("name");
        address = (String) JO.get("address");

        lat = JO.get("lat").toString();
        lng = JO.get("lng").toString();
        type = (String) JO.get("type");

        Log.i("TAG", String.format(
            "JSON Values: id=%s, name=%s, address=%s, lat=%s, lng=%s, type=%s", 
            id, name, address, lat, lng, type));
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("TAG", "exception", e);
}
```

Prints out

```
JSON Values: id=991, name=GPSname, address=GPSaddress, lat=52.948616, lng=-1.169131, type=GPStype
```

Comment: hi, okay so you gave me an idea. I created a double (lngdouble and latdouble) at the end of the initialisation of the object. then set a while loop to do nothing until their values had been filled. This finally got the map to work without crashing. The issue now, is that they are getting lat and lon of 0 each thus placing the marker in the wrong place. Is there an issue with how I am storing the lat and lon from the JSON? here is a link to the JSON: https://api.myjson.com/bins/ehzqu

Comment: @JamesDoh96 I added a bit on the JSON parsing to correctly extract the values.

Comment: @JamesDoh96 Updated my answer with an example using `AsyncTask.onPostExecute` which is probably the best practice here