# How to correctly animate a map created in Android Studio to follow the marker

Tags: javascript, android, android-maps-v2

I'm trying to update my map so that the map automatically moves to centre the marker. I want it such that if I move around, after 5 seconds, the map will animate itself to move such that the marker is central again.

Here is the code:

```js
public class TrackDifferentLocation extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    LatLng mLatlng;
    String json_string;
    public static TextView data;
    LatLng latLng = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Tracking location...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_track_different_location);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        //new FetchJSON.execute(); //Not valid syntax
        new FetchJSON().execute();
    }

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    Log.i("", "onMapReady()");
    displayMarkers();
}
    private void displayMarkers(){
        if (mMap == null)return;
        //If mLatlng is null (as the Async task has not finished, then nothing will happen.
        if(mLatlng == null) return;
        //The camera and map will then update to the new location with zoom.
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mLatlng, 17));
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(mLatlng).title(String.valueOf(mLatlng)));
    }

    //Part of menu see following
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == android.R.id.home){
            //ends the activity
            this.finish();
        }
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.mapTypeNone:
                mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);
                break;
            case R.id.mapTypeNormal:
                mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                break;
            case R.id.mapTypeTerrain:
                mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
                break;
            case R.id.mapTypeSatellite:
                mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
                break;
            case R.id.mapTypeHybrid:
                mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    class FetchJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, LatLng> {
        String JSONStr = "";
        String name, address, type = "";
        String lat = "";
        String lng = "";
        String id = "";
        //double lat, lng;
        int idInt;
        double latDouble = -1;
        double lngDouble = -1;

        protected LatLng doInBackground(String... args) {
            //LatLng latLng = null;
            try {
                //URL url = new URL("https://api.myjson.com/bins/ehzqu");
                URL url = new URL("https://api.myjson.com/bins/sv5vm");
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                Log.d("BufferedReader: ", String.valueOf(bufferedReader));
                String line = "lind";
                while (line != null) {
                    line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                    JSONStr = JSONStr + line;
                }
                Log.d("", JSONStr);
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(JSONStr);
                JSONArray array = obj.getJSONArray("server response");
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject o = array.getJSONObject(i);
                    id = o.optString("id");
                    name = o.optString("name");
                    address = o.optString("address");
                    lat = o.optString("lat");
                    lng = o.optString("lng");
                    Log.d("lat: ",lat);
                    latDouble = Double.parseDouble(lat);
                    lngDouble = Double.parseDouble(lng);
                    latLng = new LatLng(latDouble, lngDouble);
                    Log.i("JSON Values", lat + " " + lng);
                    type = o.optString("type");
                }

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.e(TAG, "FetchJSON --- " + ex.getMessage());
            }
            return latLng;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(LatLng latLng) {
            if (latLng != null) {
                mLatlng = latLng;
                displayMarkers();
            }
        }

}
}
```

Please note, for the question I have removed all imports and package.

Comment: I see you have a new URL, should that have just one location or an array of locations?

Comment: Hi, Okay so the actual URL will be to an online server, a php file that takes from a continually updating database. Therefore, the data in the database will change, so the marker will need to keep "updating" and the map will need to keep following it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To demonstrate how this can work I have changed the code which is more applicable to your code:

```
 int index = 0;
 private void loadLocation() {
     new FetchJSON().execute();
     startAutoHandler();
 }


 class FetchJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, LatLng> {

     @Override
     protected LatLng doInBackground(String... params) {
         LatLng latLng = null;
         try {
             URL url = new URL("https://api.myjson.com/bins/sv5vm");
             HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
             InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
             BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

             StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
             String line = "";
             while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                 stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
             }
             bufferedReader.close();

             String json = stringBuilder.toString();

             Log.e(TAG, "Return = " + json);
             String lat= "";
             String lng= "";
             JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);
             JSONArray array = obj.getJSONArray("server response");
             for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
                 JSONObject o = array.getJSONObject(i);

                 lat = o.optString("lat");
                 lng = o.optString("lng");
             }

             Log.e(TAG, "Lat = " + lat);
             Log.e(TAG, "lng = " + lng);

             index++;

             double adjustLat = 0.1 * index;
             double adjustLng = 0.01 * index;

             double latDouble = Double.parseDouble(lat) + adjustLat;
             double lngDouble = Double.parseDouble(lng) + adjustLng;

             latLng = new LatLng(latDouble, lngDouble);
         }
         catch (Exception ex) {
             Log.e(TAG, "doInBackground --- " + ex.getMessage());
         }
         return latLng;
     }


     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(LatLng latLng) {
         try{
             if(latLng != null){
                 mLatLng = latLng;
                 displayMarker();
             }

         }
         catch(Exception ex){
             Log.e(TAG, "onPostExecute" + ex.getMessage());
         }
     }

 }

 private void displayMarker(){
     if(mMap == null) return;
     if(mLatLng == null) return;

     mMap.clear();

     MarkerOptions markerOption = new MarkerOptions();
     markerOption.position(mLatLng);
     CameraUpdate loc = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mLatLng, 10.3f);
     mMap.animateCamera(loc);
     mMap.addMarker(markerOption);
 }

 Handler mAutoHandler = new Handler();
 long delay = 2000l; //this delay is in ms change as needed

 private void startAutoHandler(){
     try{
         Log.e(TAG, "startAutoHandler");
         mAutoHandler.postDelayed(mAutoRunnable, delay);
     }
     catch (Exception ex){
         Log.e(TAG, ex.getMessage());
     }
 }


 private Runnable mAutoRunnable = new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
         new FetchJSON().execute();
         mAutoHandler.postDelayed(mAutoRunnable, delay);
     }
 };

 private void stopAutoHandler(){
     mAutoHandler.removeCallbacks(mAutoRunnable);
 }
```

**You will need to call `stopAutoHandler();` in your `onPause()` method. Otherwise it will carry on and can cause some real issues!**

Comment: The ".postDelayed", .removeCallbacks and "mLatLng" arent recognised. I have declared mLatLng, im not quite sure why its not recognised?

Comment: @JamesDoh96 :: Did you declare `Handler mAutoHandler = new Handler();` as a class variable?

Comment: I did - it immediately also wants me to implement three new methods

Comment: @JamesDoh96 :: Take a look at the code again--just copy and past. I have changed it to be more applicable to your situation. Later in your production code you just need to adjust the "delay" and to remove the variables "adjustLat" and "adjustLng"

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!